# Initialisation patterns in Qt

Tags: qt, cocoa

I am starting to use Qt coming from a bit of Cocoa background.

In Cocoa it is rather standard to perform various initialisation/setup operations inside the application delegate or other delegates methods. What would it be the analogous pattern in Qt? Is there a virtual method or any particular place which is specifically intended for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Qt is quite different from Cocoa in this sense. In Cocoa you have a set of functions which are called in strict order and you need to do something in each function (if necessary).

In Qt/C++ you have only one necessary function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

}
```

which is the start of your program execution. In Qt in this function you will create [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) instance and [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow-members.html) instance (usually your own window instance) - if this is GUI application.

I think you may look at Qt examples, start from main function and you will understand some logic there.

Comment: Thanks, so basically with Qt you choose where to perform init operations, for example in main window constructor.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon This is up to you and to architecture of your application. You can do some of the initialization in main window constructor. Something really global may be done in the main function itself.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon Of course, you can create your own classes and put initialization there and only call/create them from mentioned places